# Insert html (unicode text) after an element

Tags: javascript

I have an element is called `divElement`:

```
<div ....>

</div>
```

and I have `p` element is called `pElement`:

```
<p ....>

</p>
```

I did:

```
divElement.appendChild(pElement);
```

and I got new element:

```
<div ....>
    <p ....>

    </p>
</div>
```

now I want to add this unicode text (▽) after the p element in order to get:

```
<div ....>
    <p ....>

    </p>
    &#9661;
</div>
```

I tried:

```
divElement.innerHTML = "&#9661;";
```

but I got:

```
<div ....>
    &#9661;
    <p ....>

    </p>
</div>
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the sign with the innerHTML of the div.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="divElement">
    <p id="pElement">
        Hello
    </p>
</div>
```

**javaScript :**

```
var element = document.getElementById("divElement");
element.innerHTML += "&#9661";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/8eTJy/)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
divElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("▽"))
```

Or, if you don't want to include the literal character:

```
var charDiv = document.createElement('div')
charDiv.innerHTML = "&#9661;"
document.body.appendChild(charDiv)
```